# Amazon EC2 image with MongoDB

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup an EC2 instance to host my MongoDB database.
Is there a ready made EC2 image with MongoDB already up and running out of the box that I can use?

Comment: It'll take about five minutes to install on a CentOS/Ubuntu AMI.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no.

There is a [feature request for this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3340). Go over there and support it.
You could do it yourself. They have written a very [clear guide on how to do it](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2).

Aren't you a lucky? Look what cloud front released today: [Amazon Web Services – MongoDB on AWS](http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf)